# Drag images with caption in WP editor

Tags: images, captions

Whenever I insert an image **without** a caption in the post, the editor makes it an object that I can select and move around / scale.

Whenever I insert an image **with** a caption, it inserts fine. I can scale the image, but I can't move it around. I think that's because the caption displays beneath the image, wich is just text.

Is there a way to make the image + caption an object or something, so that I can't select the caption text, instead selects the whole lot, so I can move it around?

Or maybe is there a hook to target images with captions in the WP editor, and just don't display the caption ( so it's treated like a normal image )?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is/was a known bug that should be fixed in WP >= 4.4

See this ticket for details: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28003